# Slashed notation in fourier font package redefinition

Tags: math-mode, fonts, formatting, symbols, fourier

I'd need to change `\slashed{}` command (`slashed` package) visualization in `fourier` package that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{slashed}
\begin{document}
$$
(i\slashed\partial-m)\psi=0
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

to more of an original look (without `fourier` package):

[image]

In other words, I'd like to slash symbol look longer and be more present.

Answer (score 1):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can do this with a combination of `fourier-otf` and STIX Two Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{fourier-otf}

% Erewhon Math lacks \not, so substitute:
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range="0338, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand\slpartial{\not\partial}

\begin{document}
\[
(i\slpartial-m)\psi=0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Erewhon Math + STIX Two Math sample]

You can try out the slash from other math fonts just as well, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{fourier-otf}

% Erewhon Math lacks \not, so substitute:
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}[range="0338, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand\slpartial{\not\partial}

\begin{document}
\[
(i\slpartial-m)\psi=0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Erewhon + New Computer Modern Book]

Answer (score 0):

You could use \big/ instead of / (see comments in slashed.sty). Add

```
\declareslashed{}{\big/}{0.05}{0}{\partial}
```

to the preamble, then

```
\[(i\slashed\partial-m)\psi=0\]
```

produces

[image]